# Are cron jobs expensive ? Or are they basically visits?

Tags: php, cron

I've been looking for the answer to this question for some time now and I find mixed answers.
Are cron jobs heavy and expensive processes that consume a lot of resources? Or are they basically hits to that page (regardless of the script that executes when cron triggers it)

I intend to use several cron jobs for several sites. Let's say I have 3 different cron jobs that'll hit certain pages every minute for 10 sites.
Does anyone have 10's or 100's of cron jobs like this in a triggering manner much like a browser hit (-wget...>/dev/null 2>&1)? If you do, do you experience additional load?

Further explanation; as you might know, WP-cron events do not take place if noone visits the WordPress site at the time of the scheduled event, until after someone comes along and triggers it.
I have some not very active WordPress sites that I plan to carry out scheduled events and I am trying to get it right.

What do you think of the online cron services ? Do they exist just because most shared users are not allowed to create cron jobs? Or is it because cron jobs slow the server down and this way you can take some load off your server?

Comment: Why don't use `cron` itself? (i.e. set your `crontab`) ?

Comment: crontab as a system service is not heavy. the online cron-trigger-thingies exists just because most shared users are not allowed to create cron jobs.

Comment: A `cronjob` is not more or less than a scheduled task and how expensive (ressource expensive) it is, depends on the task and its workload.

Comment: cron jobs are as efficient or inefficient as the code that they execute; cron itself is minimal overhead, but a badly written script that's triggered by cron will be an overhead

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Are cron jobs heavy and expensive processes that consume a lot of resources?

Not unless you make them like that.  The `cron` process itself is *very* lightweight.  All it's going to do is invoke your script.  If *your script* is a heavy and expensive process, that has nothing to do with `cron`.

> are they basically hits to that page

Kind of an odd metaphor, but I suppose so.  The `cron` job executes the script.  If that script is also used as a web page in some sense, then yes the two scenarios are comparable.  (In fact, `cron` invoking the script is probably less resource-intensive than a web server invoking the script.)  Though I recommend separating your webpage code from command-line code.  (Unless your `cron` task *is* invoking an HTTP request to a page, such as using `wget` or something of that nature.  In which case it has nothing to do with the "page" and is just invoking a command-line utility.)

> What do you think of the online cron services? Do they exists just because most shared users are not allowed to create cron jobs? Or is it because cron jobs slow the server down and this way you can take some load off your server?

The former sounds more plausible.  `cron` isn't resource-intensive.  But it does require access that some shared hosting providers don't provide.

Comment: yeah I was getting at wget by "page". What I want to do is basically pay a visit to that page every minute for WP scheduled events to run their course.

Comment: yes but, it keeps running all the time like keep waiting for the time to come.

Comment: @Jovylle: Do you mean the cron process?  Most of its time is spent idle and waiting, consuming very close to zero total resources.  (Close enough to be negligible on anything other than embedded systems with enough of a resource bottleneck that one wouldn’t be running a general purpose OS on it in the first place.)  When cron “wakes up”, all it does is invoke whatever it was told to invoke.  Whatever it invokes is consuming resources, not cron itself.

Comment: Thanks, so it's so close to zero resource consumption. Thanks because that bothers me sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Using a cron job to hit a web page to trigger application processes is not heavy.

It is a bit of a long winded approach but the act of fetching the page itelf (`wget` etc) is not heavy.

The heaviness of your application process is another matter entirely of course.

Comment: I see, thanks. So If I use the cron job to fetch a webpage via wget, it'd consume as much resources as a regular visit would.

Comment: yes, it is a regular visit to all intents and purposes